# How to remove Outlook add-in load times from the registry?

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, startup, outlook-addin

According to the following article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling

Outlook uses the median time of 5 last runs and compares it to 1 millisecond (for add-in startup). This means that if I optimize my add-in and re-install it, I should run Outlook at least 4 more times to calculate the correct value of add-in startup.
Does anybody know where this value is stored in Outlook (I guess registry)?
I tried to remove my add-in's value from the following key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\AddInLoadTimes
but it doesn't help, it still remembers it.

Answer (score 1):

Alex,

Is your add-in listed in the Disabled Items list in Outlook?

If so, you need to remove the add-in from the Disabled Items list first. To re-enable an add-in:

1. In the application, click the File tab.
2. Click the ApplicationName Options button.
3. In the categories pane, click Add-ins.
4. In the details pane, verify that the add-in appears in the Disabled Application Add-ins list.
5. The Name column specifies the name of the assembly, and the Location column specifies the full path of the application manifest.
6. In the Manage box, click Disabled Items, and then click Go.
   Select the add-in and click Enable.
7. Click Close.

Comment: Eugene,
Can we do this process somehow w/o user interaction?
Let's say we had the add-in that performed bad on startup and was added to disabled add-ins list. Then we optimized it and introduced the new version which performs good. But the add-in is still disabled. Can we enable it automatically w/o going to Outlook menu (e.g. some registry key, file on the disk, etc.)?